# How to fetch a value inside an array using helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have the following structure:

```
label:
  foo:
    bar:
    - x: hello
      y: hallo
      z: hola
```

In order to reach the value of z, I am currently doing:

```
{{ $bar := pick .Values.label.foo "bar" }}
{{ $firstItem := first $bar }}
{{ $myValue := get $firstItem "z" }}
```

Is there a more concise way to do this? I tried something like `pick .Values.label.foo[0].z` but that does not work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values structure you show is just simple string-keyed dictionaries and lists, you don't need functions like `pick` or `get`; you can just use the `.` operator to retrieve a specific key from the containing dictionary.

```
{{ $bar := .Values.label.foo.bar }}
{{ $firstItem := first $bar }}
{{ $myValue := $firstItem.z }}
```

Then you can replace the variable references with their expressions, using `(...)` parenthesis grouping if needed.

```
{{ $myValue := (first .Values.label.foo.bar).z }}
```

You can also use the standard `index` function here; I believe it is legal to mix array and map keys.  This will give you a single call, though a mix of indexing syntax.

```
{{ $myValue := index .Values.label.foo.bar 0 "z" }}
{{ $myValue := index .Values "label" "foo" "bar" 0 "z" }}
```

Comment: {{ $myValue := index .Values "label" "foo" "bar" 0 "z" }}

how can I refer label,foo,bar as values from key in values.yaml file?

Comment: The arguments to `index` are all arbitrary expressions, they don't have to be fixed strings or integers.  But, the most common case of wanting dynamic lookups I feel like I see is packaging multiple environments' values into a single `values.yaml` file, and that use case is easier to address using a fixed values layout and a separate `helm install -f` file of values per environment.

Comment: so the values.yaml looks something like 

ep:
  staging:
    ricochet:
      ash: val1
      mini: val2
    pikachu:
      ash: val3
  production:
    ricochet:
      ash: val4
      mini: val5
    pikachu:
      ash: val6

Endgoal: how to get val1 dynamically, this works, {{ (index .Values "ep" "staging" "ricochet" "ash") but how to derive staging from values.yaml itself?

Comment: Created a Gist https://gist.github.com/shubhamsre/068a2d6d408ad079c13406983255690b, nvm the above xD